# Prove that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {\sqrt{x^2+x+1}-1}{\sin(2x)}= \infty$

Tags: limits

How do I as precisely as possible prove that the following limit goes to infinity?

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {\sqrt{x^2+x+1}-1}{\sin(2x)}=\infty $$

It seems difficult. I have started the proof by selecting an $M>0$ and attempting to show that the function is $M$ is always greater than the function. My problem seems to be algebraically manipulating the function so that I can extract $|x|$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT:**

The limit is ***not*** $\infty$.  Note that

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}-1}{\sin(2x)}&=\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}-1}{\sin(2x)}\right)\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}+1}{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}+1}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{x(x+1)}{\sin(2x)}\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}+1}
\end{align}$$

Now, use $\lim_{\theta \to 0}\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\theta}=1$.

Comment: Maybe Dole didn't know this: $\sin(2x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(x)$.

Comment: @Hopeless That identity isn't required.  Just let $\theta =2x$.

Comment: Didn't see that way. Thanks!

Comment: @Hopeless You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: The real issue is that I made a sign error somewhere that made it seem like the limit was infinity on my graphic calculator. Thank you very much...

Comment: You're quite welcome.  I'm pleased to hear that you have it now!